# ASP.Net WebAPI 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have followed the tutorial located here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

However, the main difference is I am using a 3rd party library to get a list of objects which I would like to return to the client.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Get Routes</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>All Routes</h2>
        <ul id="routes" />
    </div>

    <script>
        var uri = '../api/MH_Route_Selection';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Send an AJAX request
            $.getJSON(uri)
                .done(function (data) {
                    // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        // Add a list item for the product.
                        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#routes'));
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller file:

```
namespace LMVeKanban.Controllers
{

    public class MH_Route_SelectionController : ApiController
    {
        //GET ROUTES METHOD FOR URI:  /api/MH_Route_Selection
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetRouteList()
        {
            var routeManager = new LmvRouteManager(1);

            List<Route> routes = routeManager.GetRoutes();

            return Ok(Json(routes));
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, the controller gets called and the return value routes, looks like: http://imageshack.com/a/img661/5648/ZQ59Rt.jpg

After the controller passes the list back, I get a 500 error from the server with no clue where it went wrong.

EDIT: Watching the `Ok(routes)` value shows that it has successfully converted the object:

EDIT 2: I have tried the following which also returns a 500 error in the same manner as the previous attempt

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetRouteList()
        {
            var routeManager = new LmvRouteManager(1);

            List<Route> routes = routeManager.GetRoutes();

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, routes);
        }
```

Comment: It is possible that you have an exception during serialization of route list to JSON.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `return Ok(Json(routes))`, simply using `return Ok(routes)` should be sufficient. Having said that, a 500 response usually indicates an exception so throwing a try/catch around your method and stepping through the `return` statement should allow you find out what the underlying exception is that's being thrown.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I have already tried both suggestions. When I enclose the return statement in a try/catch and step through the return, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Don't specify the format explicitly. Let content negotiation do its job.

Comment: abatishchev - can you please clarify?

Comment: Your 500 response should contain metadata about the error you're getting. Also you're probably getting an exception serializing, which means you need to implement a global exception handler.

Comment: The exception message is: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."

Comment: @user2322026 what happens if you return a different object type? I'm not sure it's a good idea to try to convert your routes in to JSON. You probably are getting an error based on the fact that you're trying to serialize a .NET Framework route into JSON, which is a smell

Comment: I should have probably clarified, the routes object is not a .NET Framework route. It is simply a list of object returned by the 3rd party library. These objects are defined by a class within the library. I have realized that there is an object within this list that is throwing an exception: " threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'". I think when it is trying to serialize the list of objects and it comes across this "errored" object, it cannot serialize it.

Comment: Have you tried creating a "Response Type" that just has the properties you're interested in, or maybe just return an anonymous type us the same interested fields? If the routes you're returning have circular dependencies  that will cause the serialization to fail. I recommend just returning the fields you need

Comment: Thanks cecilphillip. This was the correct answer to my problem. By acquiring only the fields necessary and returning those to the client, I am able to work around this problem. As it turns out the object was not loaded because the 3rd party library was using Lazy Loading.